# сделать POST запрос к серверу средствами golang

Tags: json, post, golang

Подскажите как сделать POST запрос к серверу средствами golang. Тело запроса должно содержать JSON данные.

Answer (score 6):

Простейший способ:

```
data := []byte(`{"foo":"bar"}`)
r := bytes.NewReader(data)
resp, err := http.Post("http://example.com/upload", "application/json", r)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

См. также https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Post.

https://play.golang.org/p/YzPQULc8pc

Comment: Спасибо, а можешь полный код выложить?

Comment: @user7111390 Добавил ссылку.

Comment: К сожаления ожидал другой результат, а не 
<nil> &{404 Not Found 404 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Content-Type:[text/html] Date:[Fri, 11 Nov 2016 10:46:22 GMT] Expires:[Fri, 18 Nov 2016 10:46:22 GMT] Server:[EOS (lax004/2812)] Content-Length:[454] Cache-Control:[max-age=604800]] 0xc0820ca040 454 [] false map[] 0xc0820a2000 <nil>}
Необходимо послать запрос способом post и получить ответ от сервера...

Answer (score 4):

Нашёл решение в просторах интернета:

```
func main() {
    url := "http://restapi3.apiary.io/notes"
    fmt.Println("URL:>", url)

    var jsonStr = []byte(`{"title":"Buy cheese and bread for breakfast."}`)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
    req.Header.Set("X-Custom-Header", "myvalue")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    fmt.Println("response Status:", resp.Status)
    fmt.Println("response Headers:", resp.Header)
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println("response Body:", string(body))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример запроса к микросервису:

```
func sendRequest(reader myReader) ([]byte, bool) {
  var flag bool
  var body []byte

  if err := reader.SetAllToStringsIncludeNulls(); err != nil {
    helpers.ErrHandler(err)
  } else {
    jsonReader := helpers.CreateJson(reader)
    if req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", Uri, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonReader)); err != nil {
      helpers.ErrHandler(err)
    } else {
      req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
      client := &http.Client{}
      if resp, err := client.Do(req); err != nil {
        helpers.ErrHandler(err)
      } else {
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        if body, err = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body); err != nil {
          helpers.ErrHandler(err)
        }
        flag = true
      }
    }
  }
  return body, flag
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы сделать POST запрос с телом, содержащим JSON данные, вы можете использовать функцию `http.Post` из пакета `net/http`. Вот пример кода, который делает POST запрос к URL-адресу `http://httpbin.org/post` с телом, содержащим JSON-данные:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type User struct {
    Username string `json:"username"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}

func main() {
    user := &User{
        Username: "john",
        Password: "password",
    }

    // Кодируем структуру User в JSON
    data, err := json.Marshal(user)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // Создаем новый запрос
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://httpbin.org/post", bytes.NewBuffer(data))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // Устанавливаем заголовок с типом данных в теле запроса
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    // Выполняем запрос
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // Выводим ответ от сервера
    fmt.Println(resp.Status)
}
```

В этом примере мы сначала кодируем структуру `User` в JSON с помощью функции `json.Marshal`. После того, как мы создали новый запрос с телом, содержащим JSON данные, мы устанавливаем заголовок Content-Type в запросе со значением application/json, чтобы указать серверу, что тип данных в теле запроса является JSON.

Затем мы создаем новый экземпляр http.Client и вызываем метод Do у этого экземпляра, чтобы выполнить запрос. Метод Do возвращает ответ от сервера в виде экземпляра http.Response.

Наконец, мы выводим статус ответа с помощью поля Status экземпляра http.Response.

Это основные шаги, необходимые для того, чтобы сделать POST запрос с телом, содержащим JSON данные, средствами Golang.